# Why doesn't my dynamic url in flask take the form I need it to take?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have been trying to make a `for` loop to create divs, each with an anchor to a dynamic url in my store. The resulting url should be of the form `http://127.0.0.1:5000/tienda/2` but instead takes the form `http://127.0.0.1:5000/tienda?id_producto=2`.

This is my python code. I have a page for the store and another for the item display.

```
def sql_request(data, sql_stmt):
    try:
        cursor = conexion.connection.cursor()
        sql = sql_stmt
        cursor.execute(sql)
        productos = cursor.fetchall()
        data['productos'] = productos
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Esta es la excepción: {ex}")
        data['mensaje'] = "Error"
    return data


@app.route('/tienda')
def tienda():
    return render_template("tienda.html")


@app.route('/tienda/<int:id_producto>')
def item(id_producto):
    data = {}
    sql_stmt = f"SELECT * FROM productos WHERE ID_Producto = {id_producto}"
    data = sql_request(data, sql_stmt)
    return render_template("item.html", data=data)
```

and this is the HTML code with Jinja2

```
{% for c in data.productos %}
<a class="featured-product-card" href="{{ url_for('tienda', id_producto=c[0]) }}">
    <h3>{{ c[1] }}</h3>
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = c[2])}}">
    <p>$ {{ c[3] }}</p>
    <p>{{ c[4] }}</p>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I believe you meant `url_for('item')` instead, because that is the view function name for the `/tienda/<int:id_producto>` url route.

Comment: Yess, I didn't know that I had to reference the function name and the arguments instead of the path. Thank you.